# Gitlab - my unit testing not working because of TLS10

Tags: java, sql-server, unit-testing, ssl

I got the following error :

Test > test xxxx > Test.test mytests [Id: xxxx, resultOut: xxxx , #7] STANDARD_ERROR
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]". ClientConnectionId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3422)

I looked at many of the open topics and solutions, but :

- I can't upgrade the SQL server from TLS10 to TLS12 nor TLS13 ( this is refused because old SQL server )
- I can't downgrade to java 7, I need to use java 11
- I upgraded to the latest version for jre11
  compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '9.4.0.jre11'

The gitlab-ci.yml code :

```
test:
    stage: test
    tags:
      - Linux
    script:
        - echo "Test stage"
        - ./gradlew test -i
```

These tests work perfectly on my laptop with my remote connection.
But it doesn't work on (internal ) GitLab with my remote connection

I hope there is a solution...

Comment: If the SQL Server doesn't force protocol encryption, you can set `encrypt=false` in the connection string.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-ssl-support?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I checked your solution, no luck but it doesn't help because the protocol encryption is forced...

Answer (score 0):

Finally my problem is solved.
The client was "luckely" switching to a newer SQL server which has TSL1.2.

Thanks for the help !